# how to get data from two different table in saperate row

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i have two tables lets say it `table1` and `table2`

now `table1` has a

- field1
- field2
- date

`table2` has

- field1
- date

table 1 return values `0=>[1 , 1, 15/04/2017], 1=>[2 , 1 , 17/04/2017]`

For table 2 `0=>[3 , 16/04/2017], 1=>[4 , 18/04/2017]`

now i need this record in order of date in single array such as `0=>[1 , 1 , 15/04/2017], 1=>[3 , 16/04/2017], 2=>[2 , 1 , 17/04/2017], 3=>[4 , 18/04/2017]`

I used laravel and mysql.

Comment: I am sorry i need to edit my question i have different number of `columns` in both table

Comment: select s.* form (select t1.field1,t1.date from table1 as t1 union select t2.field1,t2.date from table2 as t2 ) as s order by s.date asc

Comment: Thanks @JYoThI but it doesn't work for me. show error near `s` where you sort it.

Comment: try this select s.* form (select t1.field1,t1.date from table1 as t1 union select t2.field1,t2.date from table2 as t2 ) s order by s.date asc

Comment: again it wasn't work

Comment: what error your getting post it here @HirenMangukiya

Comment: shows error near `select s.* form (select t1.field1,t1.date from table1 as t1 union select t2.field1,t2.date from table2 as t2 )` s `order by s.date asc ` which is out from code tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141853/discussion-between-jyothi-and-hirenmangukiya).